# How do I delimit a fetched data record on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, delimiter, pipeline, text-formatting

I have a column which returns pipeline delimited records as below:

'fromState=A|Count=5|highLimit=B|status=C|presentValue=D|alarmValue=E'

Is there a way to have it as a more formatted output like:

```
'fromState=A
Count=5
highLimit=B
status=C
presentValue=D
alarmValue=E'
```

i.e.,

1. pipelines are replaced
2. each value is on a new line (optional)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the string replace function of mysql

```
SELECT REPLACE('www.mysql.com', 'w', 'Ww');
        -> 'WwWwWw.mysql.com'
```

or check out another function you could need: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

In your case you might want to replace | with \n or \r.

SELECT REPLACE(column, '|', '\r');

Comment: Thanks. The pipes are gone! But the output is as :

'fromState=A Count=5 highLimit=B status=C presentValue=D alarmValue=E'.


The "\r" does not seem to work.